# Skip building Draft merge requests in TeamCity for Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, devops, teamcity

I have a TeamCity instance and a Gitlab instance hooked up to it. Right now TC is configured to trigger on a merge request change. Where can I configure TC to bypass merge requests marked as draft? I know there is an option in Build Features > Pull Requests for GitHub: "Ignore Drafts" however I don't see one for GitLab.

Expecting to ignore merge requests marked as "draft".

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TC many years, but I think, you should set VCS Trigger Rule.
Something like this:

```
-:comment=<your_comment>:**
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-vcs-triggers.html#General+Syntax